# Laravel - artisan migrate returns error (General error: 1025 Error)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to migrate a new table in Laravel, but I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message from your screenshot, I would check your MySQL configuration file to see if you have force recovery enabled for InnoDB, e.g. `innodb_force_recovery = 1`, and change that value back to zero `innodb_force_recovery = 0` or comment the line out using a #, `# innodb_force_recovery = 1`. This config option is used for troubleshooting and recovery of your database and should be used with caution.

I have never used Ampps on a Windows machine, but I imagine the setting you are looking for is located in a `my.cnf` file somewhere within the Ampps install directory. On a Linux machine, that file is usually found at `/etc/my.cnf`, I would look in your `/path/to/Ampps/mysql/etc` folder. If you can't find that recovery config string in the my.cnf file, try using a text file editor that has built-in search tools, and search all files within the Ampps application directory for the text string 'innodb_force_recovery', it's bound to show up somewhere.

For more info on the InnoDB recovery config, see the official MySQL documentation link here: [innodb_force_recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)